# How can we install Security patches in Magento?

Tags: security, magento, patch

I got a question from my client *can you update the Magento site with the security patches?*. Can you guys please let me know that is there any module to install security patches or there are set of steps we have to implement one by one there on magento application. In either case, it will be really a great favor if you can specify the module name or steps.

Thanks
Pukhraj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the admin go to the menu System > Magento Connect > Magento Connect Manager. Once logged into that click the "Check for Upgrades" button and then "Commit Changes" button. The rest is automatic.

Your client has probably just seen a message that has been posted recently about a "Preview Release". This is not a security update that should be considered for live websites, wait until it the next message which doesn't say "RC" (meaning "Release Candidate") or "beta" (meaning "probably doesn't work").

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Magento Admin panel and open System > Magento Connect > Magento Connect Manager. Look for "Check for Upgrades" button and then "Commit Changes" button and upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

They could be talking about the security patch that was released for all versions pre 1.8 or even the php 5.4 update which is an SH script that needs to be run from command line.